# Sync audio sources programmatically

Tags: c++, audio

I have a recording in which 2 sound cards and 3 cameras are recording independently, each one has started in a different time.

Now on my video sequencer, I 'm looking for a way to sync all these sources automatically, i.e, given a set of audio parts to determine automatically the positioning of each of them related to a given position in a timeline so all audios are synced.

I know I can use my ears and a clap to sync manually, I wonder if there could be an algorithm that would aid in that.

My research so far:

1.[Audio fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint), (I used a [chromaprint](https://github.com/topics/chromaprint) library)this seems to generate same fingerprint for audios that are similar. This wouldn't help since even If I get the same fingerprint, I wouldn't know where to sync.

2.I could generate a peak map for analyzing audio like [this github project](https://github.com/rpuntaie/syncstart) and then compare the correlation, would that work?

3.[This project](https://github.com/allisonnicoledeal/VideoSync) says about "frequency constellations", I 'm not sure what this means.

Comment: Unclear: are you writing code to do this, or are you looking for external libraries, or are you looking for complete products that already does this?

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm trying to put that feature into my video sequencer,so yes I'm writing code.

Comment: How could an algorithm/program ever know how you want to sync the audio?

Comment: Option 4: Emit a tone of specified frequency and length. Synchronize on the end.

Comment: Are the cameras recording audio as well?

Comment: Is there not timecode metadata for your recordings? If your devices have roughly synchronised clocks, then that would deal with the bulk of the problem